# Sorting nested dictionary while converting string(key) into int(string)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How do I sort this given nested dictionary by int(port), and return the sorted dictionary?

Thank you in advance.

i.e. 80 would go before 443

```
port_dict1 = {'443':{  
      '...'
   },
   '80':{  
      '...'
   }
}

# Output for port_dict1
output = {80:{  
          '...'
       },
       443:{  
          '...'
       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any 'output' code, this is just the structure of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot figure what exactly you are looking for. 
Your port numbers are strings not numbers. How do you want to sort them? As strings (so that '80' is after '443') or as numbers (so that 80 is before 443)?

I am going to suppose you want to treat them as numbers, so I'm converting them to numbers.

```
 out = OrderedDict(sorted([(int(port), v) for port, v in port_dict1.iteritems()]))
```